# Repeating or removing elements from combn()

Tags: r, combinations

I want to produce a matrix where all the two possible combinations (3, or 4) from the sequence (1,2,3,4) is given while including repetition of the numbers. So I know this code

```
 X <- c(seq(1:4))
 combn(X,2)
```

Will produce all of them without repetition. However, it will not make combinations such as (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4). Is there any way combine can be used to do this and even expand it to have something like (A,A,A), (A,A,B) if we I want three combinations instead of 3.

I thought about using

```
X <- c(seq(1:4),seq(1:4))
combn(X,2)
```

But this will repeat combinations such as (1,2) in the fomat of (2,1)

Comment: You may want `gtools::combinations(4, 2, 1:4, repeats = TRUE)`

Comment: Base option: `combs <- expand.grid(1:4, 1:4) ; combs[combs[,1] <= combs[,2],]`

Comment: or `unique(apply(combn(c(1:4, 1:4), 2), 2, sort), MARGIN = 2)`

Comment: @RichardScriven: I did not even know such a simple and efficient solution existed, it is very easy to change and apply it to other combinations such as picking three instead of two of them, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @alistaire: The base option works very well with combinations of two but either a) I am not proficient enough to to make it for three combinations or b) the functions does repeat some combinations when we try three combinations. The unique(Apply()) worked really well although it took me a bit to understand how it worked. Thank you for this!

Comment: @RichardScriven, You should post it as an answer so you can get the deserved credit

Comment: To expand to choosing three, `unique(apply(combn(c(1:4, 1:4, 1:4), 3), 2, sort), MARGIN = 2)` or `combs <- expand.grid(1:4, 1:4, 1:4) ; combs[(combs[,1] <= combs[,2]) & (combs[,2] <= combs[,3]),]` or a hybrid of the two `unique(apply(expand.grid(1:4, 1:4, 1:4), 1, sort), MARGIN = 2)`

Comment: @alistaire did not think of that, thank you for the solution!